# How to add current link color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking to add a current state for the external links.

```html
<a href="#" id="DTE-slide-1">Divi Slider control #1</a>
<a href="#" id="DTE-slide-2">Divi Slider control #2</a>
<a href="#" id="DTE-slide-3">Divi Slider control #3</a>
<a href="#" id="DTE-slide-4">Divi Slider control #4</a>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $("#DTE-slide-1").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(1)").trigger("click");
    });

    $("#DTE-slide-2").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(2)").trigger("click");
    });

    $("#DTE-slide-3").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(3)").trigger("click");
    });

    $("#DTE-slide-4").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(4)").trigger("click");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Ideally, I would like to add a CSS class to the current link so I can change its color. Assume i can do this within the jquery, but not sure how! Thanks.

Comment: where is this .et-pb-controllers  in your code? for which element your triggering event?

Comment: Do you want the current class to `a#DTE-slide-1` or `.et-pb-controllers a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple update you javaScript with mine. We have to add a `active class` on the click element and remove from the other.

```js
var selector = '.links a';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
  <a href="#" id="DTE-slide-1">Divi Slider control #1</a>
<a href="#" id="DTE-slide-2">Divi Slider control #2</a>
<a href="#" id="DTE-slide-3">Divi Slider control #3</a>
<a href="#" id="DTE-slide-4">Divi Slider control #4</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Good one, If the 'a' available somewhere apart from this place. is that work for you?

Comment: In that case bind this one parent class and then target the a let me update the snippet for you.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Please let that person answer who posted question,
based on his need we have to help him out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('a').css({color: '#ffe6e6'}); 
OR
$('a').addClass('someClass');
.someClass {
color:#ffe6e6
}
```

Comment: How this code do will apply color for current link? he is asking about adding Class to the element....

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `.et-pb-controllers a` are your external links as the `#DTE-slide-X` links are internal (as you're triggering them via jQuery). To set a current CSS class to your external links, do this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        var $allLinks = $('.et-pb-controllers a');

        $("#DTE-slide-1").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $allLinks.removeClass('current-link');
            $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(1)").addClass('current-link').trigger("click");
        });

        $("#DTE-slide-2").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $allLinks.removeClass('current-link');
            $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(2)").addClass('current-link').trigger("click");
        });

        $("#DTE-slide-3").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $allLinks.removeClass('current-link');
            $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(3)").addClass('current-link').trigger("click");
        });

        $("#DTE-slide-4").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $allLinks.removeClass('current-link');
            $(".et-pb-controllers a:nth-child(4)").addClass('current-link').trigger("click");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And your current link CSS is `.current-link`, which you can style accordingly.

If this solves your question, please accept it as the answer :)